# compilation error due to type mismatch in generic class

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

**CODE:**

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? super T> supplier) {
    if (this.isPresent()) {
        return this.get();
    } else {
        return castFromSupplier(supplier);
    }
}

private static <R> R castFromSupplier(Supplier<? super R> supplier) {
    return (R) supplier.get();
}
```

**COMPILATION ERRORS:**

```
Maybe.java:74: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
return (R) supplier.get();

required: R
found: — CAP#1
where R is a type-variable:
R extends Object declared in method <R>castFromSupplier(Supplier<? super R>)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object super: R from capture of ? super R
1 warning
Grading terminated.
```

The problem essentially lies within a specific `Java` generic context that I have created (which operates in a manner quite similar to other contexts such as Optional or Log). The `orElseGet` method essentially examines whether the value exists or not. If it exists, it merely returns the value; otherwise, it obtains the value from the input supplier's `get` method.

I don't know why my code works perfectly fine in jshell, no compilation error, right output, but only in this platform that I have to submit this code it gives me this error. Any ideas that can help me debug this error statement?

Comment: Even if your code compiled, it doesn't make sense. You are calling `Supplier.get` in that 2nd path when you know there is no item. It should just be `return null` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
    if (this.isPresent()) {
        return this.get();
    } else {
        return castFromSupplier(supplier);
    }
}

private static <R> R castFromSupplier(Supplier<? extends R> supplier) {
    return (R) supplier.get();
}
```

This would be in alignment with [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)):

> ```
> public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> supplier)
> ```

---

The problem with your version is that

```
class SupplierTest {
    private static <R> R castFromSupplier(Supplier<? super R> supplier) {
        return (R) supplier.get();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Supplier<Object> so = Object::new;
        String s = castFromSupplier(so);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

compiles (with the warning about the unchecked cast) but will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` because the supplier returns an `Object` but the `test()` method expects a `String` from the `castFromSupplier()`.